# When does passing an activity to another class cause memory leaks?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory-leaks

In my Android Studio project I have an acitivty (`MainActivity`) and an object (`PurchasesHandler`). Inside the `onCreate` method of the activity, the PurchasesHandler gets instantiated like this:

`PurchasesHandler purchasesHandler = new PurchasesHandler(MainActivity.this, ...)`

From reading a lot of articles about memory leaks I know that one should be very cautious when passing an activity, since this can lead to memory leaks. But I guess that passing the activity does not necessarily lead to memory leaks, right?

So let's go further and look into the `PurchasesHandler`. This handler contains a simple `AlertDialog` builder which looks like this:

```
private void showBillingResponseDialog(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
```

As you can see, I am referencing the activity in this method, but I guess that this also cannot lead to memory leaks, right? If so, can someone explain why? I find it intuitive that it is like that, but I cannot explain, why it is like that.

So let's look at one more code snippet from the `PurchasesHandler`:

```
public void sampleMethod() {
        BillingClient billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(this) // Passes the onPurchasesUpdated listener of this class
                .build();
```

In this code snippet I am setting a listener which references the `PurchasesHandler` itself (because of .setListener(**this**)). My guess would be now, that there exists a memory leak, since the listener holds a reference to the `PurchasesHandler` and the `PurchasesHandler` holds a reference to the activity. This would mean, that the activity cannot be deallocated/removed from the heap, right?

If my assumptions are true, is there any nice way to get rid of the memory leak? I know that I should unregister listeners, but for the `BillingClient` there exists no unregister option. Only a `endConnection()` method, but this method sometimes doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct if any of the code that is keeping reference to an activity it can cause the memory leak. This is why it is recommended to release the references when activity is stopped. If your library doesn't provide remove listener function then setting the listener object to **null** will release all the references of the activity. Also watchout for the alert dialog as well

Answer (score 0):

Asumming you have a implementation of PurchaseHandler in SomeActivity then in onStop or OnDestroy of the activity assign PurchaseHandlerObject = null

Other approach is to use WeakReference
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/finally-understanding-how-references-work-in-android-and-java-26a0d9c92f83

Comment: If I set the PurchasesHandlerObject to null, I can still see new instances in the profiler.

Comment: can you please share the code how you have implemented this
did you mark the instance to null in onStop  or onDestroy?

Comment: in onPause of the activity I set ```purchasesHandler = null;```

Comment: Cool to be frank I haven't check this thing in Profiler as you have marked the instance to null in onPause just validate in onStop if (purchaseHandler == null) --> if it is null then there shouldn't be any memory leak if you still see that it is not null then I need to check the code :P

Comment: It actually is null, but the profiler shows me additional instances for each purchasesHandler I created. So if I create a PurchasesHandler in onResume and set it to null in onPause, then an instance is added. However, if I first make sure, that the BillingClient in the PurchasesHandler gets disconnected or is null, then I only have 1 instance of PurchasesHandler, no matter how ofter I resume the activity. Seems like the background process of the BillingClient doesn't get canceled, when the PurchasesHandler gets nullified.

Comment: ** To my knowledge ** Now the only way to tell if things are right is after looking at the code or else give weak reference a try and see if things work for you as required or else if you don't mind share the code link

Comment: I cannot show the code for the project but where would you implement the weak reference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203475/discussion-between-manoj-mohanty-and-leon).